# Inline styles bad for accessibility?

Tags: css, accessibility

I'm styling an XML feed that has inline styles. So I'm going to override the inline styles with styles in a CSS file. I know that in an ideal world the XML feed shouldn't have inline styles or those styles should be stripped out, but this isn't possible.

Are their any downsides to doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't the CSS from the stylesheet be overridden by the ones that are inline?

Comment: I thought I could use more selectors or !important. Thanks

Comment: @jdln, yes !important will override all. But it's not recommended.

Comment: I know, but I need to override the styles and I cant change the html on the page. In this case it seems acceptable. Thanks

Comment: It is terribly depreacted, but *should* do something. http://jsfiddle.net/5R3zg/

Comment: above code increase the font size by 5 times then native font size of browser

Comment: Yeah, it will definitely do something. How are you importing your XML? It's possible you can parse and clean deprecated tags from the code.

Comment: @diEcho, when I remove it with firebug the page doesn't change so do only certain browsers use this? Also the text is currently too small but from what you've said it sounds like it should be too big.

Comment: @clairesuzy its the same project yes, but I felt it was a different question. Thanks

Comment: @Pekka your jsfiddle example works on my browser but the same browser is ignoring the styles in the page im talking about. Is the code so depreciated that browsers will always ignore it if font-style is available instead? Thanks

Comment: @jdln nope, but there is probably some other CSS overriding the font size

Comment: But its not like em where I would need to set a pixel dimension to make sure it didn't affect the size? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jdln, you are right ; written clearly **[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font)**

> The HTML Font Element () defines the font size, color and face for its content.

as well as

> Do not use this element! Though once
>   normalized in HTML 3.2, it was
>   deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same
>   time as all elements related to
>   styling only, then obsoleted in HTML
>   5. – diEcho 0 secs ago edit

Comment: OK, so will all browsers ignore it if font-style is applied to the element? Thanks

Comment: Hm, how can this be the answer to your question? I thought you wanted to override the inline styles with an external style?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to override inline css through an external stylesheet is by using `!important`.

```
<span class="error" style="color:red">text</span>
```

Which can be overriden by using this:

```
.error {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

But to answer your question, this is not bad for accessibility. But it is from a coding point of view a bad thing to do, because 1 month later you will look at that html and wonder why that text is blue and not red.

Comment: Imperfect I know but thanks. I just wanted to make sure their weren't any consequences I was unaware of.