# Accesability issue with incorect inline styles?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Im importing an XML feed which has some inline styles. However the styles are written incorrectly and dont actually do anything:

```
<font size="5"> text here </font>
```

I know that in an ideal world the xml feed wouldn't container inline styles or I would have a way to strip them out but thats not possible. Is their any accessibility or other issues with this code that doen't seem to do anything?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inline styles bad for accessibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108671/inline-styles-bad-for-accessibility)